# How to style links within other elements

Tags: html, css

I have this structure

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu sf-navbar sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
  <li id="level1-home" class="current sfHover sf-breadcrumb">
     <a href="/Admin/Home/Index">
  ...
```

And I'd like to style the `<a>` tags without affecting any other links in the site.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Targeting by ID

In your provided code you have an `id` of "nav" on your `ul` element. This can be used to specify the container of the anchors you'd like to target:

```
#nav a {
  color: orange;
}
```

This will affect all `a` elements within (regardless of nested depth) an element that has the `id` of "nav".

#### Targeting by Unique Path

Examine the parents of your links for uniqueness. Links that fall within a `nav` element, within a `header` element can be styles like this:

```
header nav a {
  color: red;
}
```

Links that fall within a `nav` contained within a `footer` could be addressed like this:

```
footer nav a {
  color: green;
}
```

#### Disclaimer

The `header`, `footer`, and `nav` tags are all HTML5 constructs. To broad support across older browsers, be sure to include the [HTML5Shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) when working with these tags.

Comment: There is no need for using 2 childs (header nav a) when there is an id already in the code (the ul with #nav). The same with nav#header (ids are unique, so no need for the nav tag there).

Comment: @Cmorales You're absolutely correct - I had missed that fact in the OP's example.

Answer (score 5):

```
nav a { /*affect only links in the navbar */ }
```

Comment: Since this is HTML5 we can use the `<nav>` element in our declaration

Comment: There could be other nav elements, that's why #nav would be more specific (there is a #nav already in the code). However, nav a would do the trick probably (not likely to be an issue to have 2 navs)

Comment: True. There are several ways to improve upon this depending on how specific we need to get